# Error installing ubuntu server 14:04 / 15:04

Tags: server

I'm trying to install ubuntu server on an notebook, the problem is that his nics (wired and wireless) are by default turned off which causes a error when detecting network hardware, is there a way to turn on them when installing ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well no response so far, for me the solution was to use debian server, it works very well in this situation , besides being a very similar operating system.